# How do I merge 2 JSON arrays for $http data?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have 2 models, both JSON data. One is generated by user input in a form, the other is data provided by an API and is modified by user input in the same form.

here is the form in the view:

```
<form method="post" name="form" role="form" ng-controller="ContactFormController as ctrl" ng-submit="form.$valid && ctrl.sendMessage(input, ctrl.cartItems)" novalidate>
<p ng-show="success">Thanks for getting in touch!</p>
<p ng-show="error">Something went awry with your submission!, please try again.</p>
<div class="formgroup">
    <legend>Express Order Form</legend>
    <div id="formHeader"></div>
<fieldset>
<div class="inputItem">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="input.name" required>
</div>
<div class="inputItem">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="input.email" required>
</div>
<div class="inputItem">
    <label for="School">School:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="school" name="school" ng-model="input.school" required>
</div>
<!-- Form Items -->
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.cartItems">
    <div class="col-sm-6 cartItemLabel" ng-bind="item.label"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 inputItem">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-change="ctrl.updateSub(item)" ng-model="item.qty">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 inputItem">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-model="item.value">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 inputItem">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-model="item.subTotal">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Form Items -->
<div class="inputItem">
    <label for="messsage">Message:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="messsage" name="message" ng-model="input.message" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
    <label for="honeypot">I promise I'm not a bot</label>
    <input type="text" id="honeypot" name="honeypot" ng-model="input.honeyPot">
</div>
```

Here is the model that is NOT generate by the form above:

```
self.cartItems = [
        {'id': 1, 'label': "Band-Aids (box)", 'value': 1.5, 'qty': 0, 'subTotal': 0},
        {'id': 2, 'label': "Binders – 1/2”", 'value': 6.5, 'qty': 0, 'subTotal': 0},
        {'id': 3, 'label': "Binders – 1”", 'value': 6.5, 'qty': 0, 'subTotal': 0},
        {'id': 4, 'label': "Binders – 1 1/2”", 'value': 7.5, 'qty': 0, 'subTotal': 0},
        {'id': 5, 'label': "Binders – 2”", 'value': 8.5, 'qty': 0, 'subTotal': 0}
    ]
```

I need to upload all data from both JSON arrays to an API. I tried to concatenate the 2 JSON arrays like this (the function that is called on submit in the form):

```
self.sendMessage = function( input, items ) {
   var output = input.concat(items); 
   ....[on to my $http call]
```

but I get a type error.
Forgive me if I left out info you need; I am a newbie to Angular.

Comment: What error are yu getting?

Comment: @mohamedrias - TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at self.sendMessage

Comment: But from your form, the `input` model in your form isn't an array. It's an object with keys `email`, `name` & `school`. What you probably want to do is: `var output = [input].concat(items);`

I haven't tested this, but i think it should work.

Comment: @RogerCreasy when you use input.concat(items) is the result as you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all who helped me on this issue, a big thank you!

@ragingprodigy put me on the right track.

I had to change the input within the method in my controller to:

```
var output = [input].concat(items);
```

I also had to change the form elements' binding to include the controller (as ctrl)

```
ng-model="ctrl.input.[each form element on input]"
```

Thanks again to all who helped! I hope this answer helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to take a look at angular.extend, I think it should solve your problem.

[angular.extend doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

Comment: appropriate to be a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

A type error usually means that a type is not what you expected.  I would guess that input is not an array.  Try changing your code to this:

```
 var output = items.concat(input);
```

**Edit**: To further track down the issue, you can add a `debugger;` statement in your code to break in the code at runtime.  Then you can verify the types are what you expect by opening the dev tools console in your browser while running that piece of code.

Comment: Thanks. The code changed shifted my error to my API. So, I think you are onto something. I'll try `debugger; `

Comment: If input" isn't what you (or rather, the API) expects, that would make sense.  It would still be added to the array, but your API would puke if it can't deserialize.  Definitely try the breakpoint to confirm.

Comment: actually, adding the cartItems bit is what broke the code. It worked perfectly with just the input model.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could provide full code for investigation.
My guess is that you have an issue calling sendMessage, since 'input' is part of your model try calling it like this:

```
 self.sendMessage = function(items ) {
   var output = self.input.concat(items); 
}
```

or if you have defined scope:

```
self.sendMessage = function(items ) {
       var output = $scope.input.concat(items); 
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, I get : TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
    at self.sendMessage

Comment: I am still struggling with this. Here is my code with the most recent suggestion I tried implemented:
https://gist.github.com/RogerCreasy/7af52d77764d81c070b0

Answer (score 0):

I usually use jquery with angular. 
If this is your case, you could use $.extend (true, {}, obj1, obj2)
put your most valuable object at the end (probably the edited by the user), just in case you have the same property on both and wanna stay with only one of them.